# how to animated swiper.js slider with full-width background

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I have already tried to create a slider/carousel using Swiper.js exactly like the one on this site: https://stinna-it.nl/alle-projecten. I have also managed to achieve the text effect, however, I am having trouble with the background image. I added an image tag to the HTML, but it is not updating when the slide changes. I created an array of images and tried to update them according to the slide index number, but I keep getting an error stating "Unable to get image of undefined".

```js
var images = [
  {
    id: "0",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/12/15/dfE2sy.aura-blobb.png",
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/12/15/df3XIx.almond-key.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/12/15/dfE2sy.aura-blobb.png",
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/12/15/dfE2sy.aura-blobb.png",
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    img: "https://i.im.ge/2022/12/15/dfE2sy.aura-blobb.png",
  },
];
const img = document.querySelector(".prjctbg");
// for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
//   console.log(images[i].img);
//   img.src = images[i].img;
// }
var swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container", {
  pagination: {
    el: ".swiper-pagination",
    clickable: true,
  },
  spaceBetween: 1,
  slidesPerView: 2.5,
  centeredSlides: true,
  roundLengths: true,
  loop: true,
  loopAdditionalSlides: 30,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
    prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
  },
  on: {
    slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
      var imgElement = document.querySelector(".prjctbg");

      // Get the current slide index
      var slideIndex = this.realIndex;
      imgElement.src = images[slideIndex].img;
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.projectSlider {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  .prjctbg {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
    filter: blur(8px);
    -webkit-filter: blur(8px);
  }
}
.swiper-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.swiper-slide {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  transition: all 200ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  text-align: center;
  //   transition: cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1);
  p {
    overflow: hidden;
    color: #fff;
    span {
      transform: translateY(100px);
      transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s,
        transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
      display: block;
    }
  }
  h1 {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 3em;
    line-height: 100%;
    transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s,
      transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
    margin: 0px;
    transform: scale(0.5);
  }
  &.swiper-slide-active {
    p {
      opacity: 1;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
      span {
        transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s,
          transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
        transform: translateY(0px);
        display: block;
      }
    }
    h1 {
      transition: transform 1000ms cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s,
        transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.165, 0.84, 0.44, 1) 0.2s;
      transition-delay: 0.15s;
      transform: scale(1);
    }
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
       <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/css/swiper.css"
    />
   <div class="projectSlider">
      <img src="" alt="" class="prjctbg" />
      <div class="swiper-container">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  Audiovisual <br />
                  Design
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> Video Installation</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  Exhibition <br />
                  Design
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> Multimedia Exhibition</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  Texts and <br />
                  Images
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> website + Print Magazine </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  Material and <br />
                  Light
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> Short Video</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  Dimension <br />
                  Design
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> Rendered Image </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="swiper-slide">
            <div class="swiper-slide-container">
              <div class="details">
                <h1 class="elmt">
                  App <br />
                  Design
                </h1>
                <p class="elmt">
                  <span> Sustainability App</span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Add Pagination -->
        <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
        <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/4.2.0/js/swiper.js"></script>
```

Comment: gut feeling here, says that if it is undefined, than it is out of scope.

Answer (score 1):

Use the find function to reference the image by it's .id property, rather than its index / key:

```js
imgElement.src = images.find( el => el.id == slideIndex ).img;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, but I want to know how to animate it and if anyone knows a better solution to this problem, please share it.
this is the updated code:

```
 on: {
slideChangeTransitionStart: function () {
  var imgElement = document.querySelector(".prjctbg");

  // Get the current slide index
  var slideIndex = this.realIndex;
  console.log(slideIndex);
  for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (slideIndex == images[i].id) {
      img.src = images[slideIndex].img;
    }
  }
},
```

},

Comment: so the key which you were using was incorrect then?

Comment: I've updated my answer to use Array.find function, which returns one element of an array based on search conditions.

Comment: If you want an answer for animating or transitioning, you should post a new question

Comment: I want that it would animate like this site: https://stinna-it.nl/alle-projecten

Comment: you should post this as an new question, rather than just a comment.  It's how this site is set up and you will get more answers that way.  I won't help you further in these comments. :) You are doing great! Keep learning and growing as a developer.

Answer (score -1):

I am unfamiliar with Swiper.js. But I went ahead and solved and streamlined your problem within React.js.

Here is how I would approach said problem (not knowing your situation and full use cases).

[Index File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaDJZ.png)

[CSS File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsSEn.png)

LiveDemo: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-frog-yzttmb?file=/src/styles.css

It may seem really complicated, but all I am simply doing is mapping through your images and rendering them with some CSS conditionals.

The reason I chose to map over the photos for the PageButtons section, so as we add new photos to the data - we don't have to do any shoulder work, and the photo and new carousel button will automatically be added.

Ultimately, I would kind of build my own carousel, I noticed you had a ton of extra images as well that were the same image. I went and added one more to display the point.

The only task you are now left with are figuring out your animations - which I would recommend away from too many animations for optimization reasons, but you will do as you want.

Cheers,

Comment: Please include your code in a code snippet and not in an image